# Error when running Theano on a cluster with multiple nodes

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

I'm running a script which fits identical an `PyMC3` model to different datasets, on a cluster with multiple nodes.
For parallelization within a node I use `joblib` and to use multiple nodes I just run the same script seperately for each node. After some time I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "fit_multiple_events.py", line 167, in fit_reparametrized_model
    # Plot model
  File "../utils.py", line 46, in run_sampling
    step=xo.get_dense_nuts_step(),
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/exoplanet/quadpotential.py", line 203, in get_dense_nuts_step
    return pm.NUTS(potential=potential, model=model, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/hmc/nuts.py", line 152, in __init__
    super().__init__(vars, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/hmc/base_hmc.py", line 72, in __init__
    super().__init__(vars, blocked=blocked, model=model, dtype=dtype, **theano_kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/arraystep.py", line 228, in __init__
    vars, dtype=dtype, **theano_kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/model.py", line 723, in logp_dlogp_function
    return ValueGradFunction(self.logpt, grad_vars, extra_vars, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/model.py", line 462, in __init__
    inputs, [self._cost_joined, grad], givens=givens, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 317, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1841, in orig_function
    fn = m.create(defaults)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1715, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 699, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 1091, in make_all
    impl=impl))
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 955, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 858, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1217, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1157, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1624, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1155, in module_from_key
    module = self._get_from_hash(module_hash, key, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 1055, in _get_from_hash
    key_data.add_key(key, save_pkl=bool(key[0]))
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 519, in add_key
    self.save_pkl()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 540, in save_pkl
    with open(self.key_pkl, 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/gpfs1/home/fb90/.theano/compiledir_Linux-2.6-el6.Bull.122.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.4-Santiago-x86_64-3.7.3-64/tmpotc6hmx4/key.pkl'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fit_multiple_events.py", line 232, in <module>
    trajectory = ca.trajectory.Trajectory(event, model.t0, model.u0, model.tE)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 934, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/fb90/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
FileNotFoundError: [Errno The following error happened while compiling the node] Elemwise{Composite{(i0 - ((i1 * i2) + i3))}}(TensorConstant{[52.651766...48194605]}, Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1}.0, Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0): '\n' -> 'No such file or directory'
slurmstepd: task_p_post_term: rmdir(/dev/cpuset/slurm140858/slurm140858.4294967294_0) failed Device or resource busy
```

This happens only when I'm running a script on multiple nodes of the cluster at the same time. It doesn't appear to happen if I just use a single node.

I found a thread from 2015 mentioning the same problem with no solution:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/Pi4zQpfn5Ts

I'm using the latest version of Theano, `1.0.4`.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? i have the same one :(